# Trying to access a key-value pair in a nested dictionary: where am I going wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, api, dictionary

Newbie here. Thanks in advance for your patience!

I'm using requests in Pandas to get info from an API. Here are the API results:

```
{
"data": [
{
"all_awardings": [],
"allow_live_comments": false,
"author": "qu1et1",
"author_flair_css_class": null,
"author_flair_richtext": [],
"author_flair_text": null,
"author_flair_type": "text",
"author_fullname": "t2_will3i",
"author_patreon_flair": false,
"author_premium": false,
"awarders": [],
"can_mod_post": false,
"contest_mode": false,
"created_utc": 1577837075,
"domain": "open.spotify.com",
"full_link": "https://www.reddit.com/r/SpotifyPlaylists/comments/eib232/instant_addiction_jan_2020_update_your_selective/",
"gildings": {},
"id": "eib232",
"is_crosspostable": true,
"is_meta": false,
"is_original_content": false,
"is_reddit_media_domain": false,
"is_robot_indexable": true,
"is_self": false,
"is_video": false,
"link_flair_background_color": "",
"link_flair_richtext": [],
"link_flair_template_id": "933b36a2-d08e-11e8-883e-0e5f4502fa8a",
"link_flair_text": "Various",
"link_flair_text_color": "dark",
"link_flair_type": "richtext",
"locked": false,
"media": {
"oembed": {
"description": "We and our partners use cookies to personalize your experience, to show you ads based on your interests, and for measurement and analytics purposes. By using our website and our services, you agree to our use of cookies as described in our Cookie Policy.",
"height": 380,
```

I'm trying to get the contents of the "description" key. I've tried:

```
data = getPushshiftData(after,last_epoch)
for post in data:
description = post[media][oembed]["description"]
```

Since media and oembed are dictionaries, I'm not putting them in quotes.

I'm getting an unhashable type: 'dict' error. Could someone help me as to where I'm going wrong?

Edit: I've tried putting media and oembed in quotes, and it's giving me a key error for 'media'.

```
while int(after) < last_epoch:
data = getPushshiftData(after,last_epoch)

for post in data:
    tmp_time = post['created_utc']
    timestamps.append(tmp_time)
    tmp_id = post['id']
    post_ids.append(tmp_id)
    tmp_full_link = post['full_link']
    full_link.append(tmp_full_link)
    
   
    tmp_description = (post['media']['oembed']['description']) #error
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?  What are the values of `media` and `oembed`?  One of those is probably the dict that's giving you the error - you can't use a dict as the key in another dict!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to access it with quotes, I saved your output JSON in a file and read it into a dict using `json.load`:

```
with open('1.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for rec in data['data']:
    print(rec['media']['oembed']['description'])
```

**Output:**

```
We and our partners use cookies to personalize your experience, to show you ads based on your interests, and for measurement and analytics purposes. By using our website and our services, you agree to our use of cookies as described in our Cookie Policy.
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding!

I'm trying this in my own code, and I'm now getting a key error for media. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: you could, before ```print(rec['media']...)``` try a ```print(rec)```.   that should clarify what ```rec``` is

Comment: thank you both! The try and except worked for me. The issue was that there wasn't a "media" key for every entry. 

Super new to programming, and really appreciate your time in helping!